# Looping through a JSON array to API

Tags: python, json, api, loops

I am new to Python and facing issues with my code.

I am fetching the data and converted it in JSON format and storing the in one variable.

Output of print(data) is

```
['{"lot_no":"4f64-b946-d71fdf14f3ae",,"batch_status":"pending","recipients":[{},{}]}', 
'{"lot_no":"1b5a-c5fc-41ac-b798-b7afd835e8c6",,"lot_status":"pending","recipients":[{"acocunt":"-370816706760555322764049398323519400","snp":"456786545678","tracking_code":"User1","template_id":1,"communication_type":"phone",,"lang":"en",,"template_data":{"price":"12.34","paymentType":"visa"}},{"acocunt":"56785678976576545678","snp":"456786545678","tracking_code":"1256","template_id":1,"communication_type":"phone",,"lang":"en","template_data":{"price":"94.27","paymentType":"cash"}}]}', 
'{"lot_no":"ad96-5a8f-4dad-9fad-ba93f682d8b5",,"lot_status":"pending","recipients":[{"acocunt":"-3708167062764049398323519400","snp":"456786545678","tracking_code":"User1","template_id":1,"communication_type":"phone",,"lang":"en",,"template_data":{"price":"12.34","paymentType":"visa"}},{"acocunt":"56785654567876545678","snp":"456786545678","tracking_code":"2568","template_id":1,"communication_type":"phone",,"lang":"en","template_data":{"price":"94.27","paymentType":"cash"}}]}', 
'{"lot_no":"07f-fdf3-4fdf-9fa7-32b6b92fb477",,"lot_status":"pending","recipients":[{},{}]}', 
'{"lot_no":"1eae1-0644-489c-917c-f7de7751fac9",,"lot_status":"pending","recipients":[{},{}]}', 
'{"lot_no":" -fb29-44d7-a5c8-7ee1a55e8fe3",,"lot_status":"pending","recipients":[{},{}]}']
```

I want to remove [ (at starting) and ] (at ending)

I have tried with newdata = data[1:-1] but it is returning []

I need to send these lots to API, i should do this each lot and loop through the lot.

I am getting the count of these lots (for above code it's 6)

The below code is working for one lot (ad96-5a8f-4dad-9fad-ba93f682d8b5) if I pass the data of that lot.

```
import requests

url = "url/api /notify/lot/ ad96-5a8f-4dad-9fad-ba93f682d8b5"
payload = '{"lot_no":"07f-fdf3-4fdf-9fa7-32b6b92fb477",,"lot_status":"pending","recipients":[{},{}]}', 
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Authorization': inputtokenhere,
    'User-Agent': "PostmanRuntime/7.3",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Host': "ext-api-support-int.godrej.com",
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'Content-Length': "697",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }
response = requests.request("PUT", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

I am looking to loop each lot details in API code, how can I do so?

Comment: The strings in the list don't seem to be valid JSON.

Comment: data is list so `print()` will always display `[ ]` to inform you that it displays list but these chars are not part of data. Use `for payload in data: request.put(... data=payload)`

Comment: This one is working for me.... Data_new = str(data)[1:-1]

Comment: don't convert it to string but use `for`-loop directly with `data` - `for payload in data: requests.put(... data=payload)`. It seems you don't know how to work with list/array.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array from the JSON string, however in the provided is not in proper JSON format.

Converting JSON string to an array:

`import json
 json_string = '[{}]'
 data = json.loads(x)
 print (data)`

After that, you can loop through the array elements and perform your necessary operations.

Answer (score 0):

if you have list with many items then use `for`-loop to get every item separately and send it

**EDIT:** I added code which gets `lot_no` from string and use with `url`. It needs to replace double `',,'` with single `,` in `item` to create correct JSON data.

```
data = ['{"lot_no":"4f64-b946-d71fdf14f3ae",,"batch_status":"pending","recipients":[{},{}]}', 
'{"lot_no":"1b5a-c5fc-41ac-b798-b7afd835e8c6",,"lot_status":"pending","recipients":[{"acocunt":"-370816706760555322764049398323519400","snp":"456786545678","tracking_code":"User1","template_id":1,"communication_type":"phone",,"lang":"en",,"template_data":{"price":"12.34","paymentType":"visa"}},{"acocunt":"56785678976576545678","snp":"456786545678","tracking_code":"1256","template_id":1,"communication_type":"phone",,"lang":"en","template_data":{"price":"94.27","paymentType":"cash"}}]}', 
'{"lot_no":"ad96-5a8f-4dad-9fad-ba93f682d8b5",,"lot_status":"pending","recipients":[{"acocunt":"-3708167062764049398323519400","snp":"456786545678","tracking_code":"User1","template_id":1,"communication_type":"phone",,"lang":"en",,"template_data":{"price":"12.34","paymentType":"visa"}},{"acocunt":"56785654567876545678","snp":"456786545678","tracking_code":"2568","template_id":1,"communication_type":"phone",,"lang":"en","template_data":{"price":"94.27","paymentType":"cash"}}]}', 
'{"lot_no":"07f-fdf3-4fdf-9fa7-32b6b92fb477",,"lot_status":"pending","recipients":[{},{}]}', 
'{"lot_no":"1eae1-0644-489c-917c-f7de7751fac9",,"lot_status":"pending","recipients":[{},{}]}', 
'{"lot_no":" -fb29-44d7-a5c8-7ee1a55e8fe3",,"lot_status":"pending","recipients":[{},{}]}'] 

import json

for item in data:

    d = json.loads(item.replace(',,', ','))
    lot = d['lot_no']
    print(lot)

    #lot = item.split(':')[1].split(',')[0].strip('"')
    #print(lot)

    url = "url/api/notify/lot/" + lot

    response = requests.put(url, data=item, headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
```

Comment: I have to pass lot_no to URL in each iteration dynamically. Is there anyway?                         url = "url/api /notify/lot/ ad96-5a8f-4dad-9fad-ba93f682d8b5"

Comment: url is a string so you can use all string functions - like concatenation `"url" + "lot"` or string formating `"url {}".format("lot")` or in Python 3.6 or 3.7 f-string `f"url {item}"`.

Comment: item on list is also string so you can also use string function to get value - ie. `split(':')`, `split(',')` , etc. You can try `lot = item.split(':')[1].split(',')[0].strip('"')`

Comment: if you replace double `,,` with single `,` then you get correct JSON data and then you can convert it to Python's dictionary and get `lot` from dictionary: `d = json.loads(item.replace(',,', ','))` and `lot = d['lot_no']`

Comment: Thanks a lot Furus. I am new to this, may i know how can i mark this as correct answer?

Comment: I don't know how to mark correct answer because I never ask any question on Stackoverflow. As I know new users may have to wait some time before they can mark answer as correct.